# TCP traffic slows down udp traffic

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I am trying to wrote a VR remote gaming system.
A TCP video streaming program which only send H.264 frames of screenshots from desktop to my android phone. and an Android app sending orientation data in UDP to desktop. Everything was tested in local network

If I only run the sensor sender program. I can see the game camera rotating in real-time.

But if I run the two program at the same time. TCP Screen streaming is always smooth but sensor data receiving start to delay.

Then I lower down the sending fps. It gets smoother but still not acceptable.

TCP traffic has 500KBps~1000KBps

UDP has 600Bps

Does it mean network congestion occuring? How can I overcome this?

What if I change video streaming protocal to UDP? but an I-frame may be larger than 65KB

Comment: That's far too broad to answer, but I would suggest you start by running both of your programs but mocking communication (Do real work, at real refresh rates, just use static image data instead of a live feed)

Comment: *Traffic* slows down other *traffic.* On the network as in life. It has nothing to do with TCP and UDP specificaly. Neither has special privileges in the network.